# How to watermark a Petrel project?

Tags: ocean, petrel

in our university we are running reservoir engineering course based on a Petrel plugin. The student is supposed to bring up a "Digital oilfield" plugin, log in with his credentials and start filling his project with the data, requesting 2D/3D seismic, logs etc. from the server. If something (e.g. a crash) happens during the data transfer, he can download the data again.

To prevent cheating, however, this data must be made available only for him (he pays virtual money for every piece of data). So his copy of server data is watermarked with his own key, and the plugin should only allow loading data if the project key is the same. To do this, the key has to be embedded into his copy of a Petrel project once he starts downloading data.

What would be the best way to achieve this? I poked into the custom data types creation and probably this approach isn't fit for this purpose, since the watermark must not be visible or modifyable by the student.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to store this identifier as a custom object within the Petrel project but not make it visible in the Petrel tree, you can use the ElementBehavior API to specify that it should be hidden from the user.

Comment: This is useful information! Although, on the second thouhgt, `IElementBehavior` might not be what I need. I didn't have time to experiment with the custom data yet, I assume that it will store a .ptd file bearing a data type in the Petrel folder. Unless this information is stored in the .pet file itself, it'll be a matter of minutes to find which file causes the project to get "tethered". Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Objects that use basic .NET serialization will currently be serialized into one of the core Petrel data files.  This is generally not a best practice because it isn't a scalable solution.  However, for a single identifier in a non-production workflow, this shouldn't really be an issue.  It isn't the .pet file, but it is a mandatory file for reloading the project, so it can't simply be deleted.